# java.beans.PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(Locale.class) returns null in spring

Tags: java, spring

According to  [spring ref docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion):

> Spring uses the java.beans.PropertyEditorManager to set the search path for property editors that might be needed.

But I'm getting null  here:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import java.beans.PropertyEditor;
import java.beans.PropertyEditorManager;
import java.util.Locale;

public class DefaultEditorsTest {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new
                            ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");

        PropertyEditor editor = PropertyEditorManager.findEditor(Locale.class);
        System.out.println(editor);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sep 13, 2016 8:47:29 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@17f052a3: startup date [Tue Sep 13 20:47:29 CDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 13, 2016 8:47:29 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-config.xml]
null
```

My spring-config.xml is actually registering a couple of beans. Why I'm getting null? If this is not a right way then how to get instance of spring's LocaleEditor and others? I want to use it in a swing application and  I will probably be using many provided by spring so I don't want to register them manually.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BeanWrapperImpl.(http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapperImpl.html)

> Note: Auto-registers default property editors from the org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors package, which apply in addition to the JDK's standard PropertyEditors.

```
BeanWrapperImpl wrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(bean);  
PropertyEditor editor = wrapper.getDefaultEditor(Locale.class);
System.out.println(editor);
```

Comment: Thanks abaghel, that works. But  for my understanding, isn't there a global registry for property editors? From your approach it looks like editors are recreating every time a bean is created (bean wrapper needs a bean class or name, null doesn't work), is that correct? Are different default editors created for different beans, may be depending on bean fields?

Comment: BeanWrapperImpl instance without bean will also work and will load PropertyEditors. try BeanWrapperImpl wrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl();

Comment: Great..! that works too. I'm assuming it's the only best way around for my problem. BTW I have been struggling with one more issue. Can I get the list of all registered default editors in case if I use empty constructor in 'new BeanWRapperImpl()'. Thanks again abaghel

Comment: I don't think there is a method which can return a list of default editors. PropertyEditorRegistrySupport.createDefaultEditors() is called when you create BeanWrapperImpl instance and this creates a private Map. ProprtyEditors registered by BeanWrapperImpl is available at http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/package-summary.html